# How to mount NFS in Knative v0.23?

Tags: kubernetes, knative, knative-serving

We encountered a need to mount NFS when using Knative v0.23, but PVC was not supported by Knative until v1.2. Upgrading the Knative version carries certain risks for us. Is there a way to use NFS in Knative v0.23? If not, how should we evaluate the compatibility risks brought by upgrading the Knative version?

We understand that upgrading the Knative version can solve this problem, but there is a certain compatibility risk for us. So we want to know if there is a way to mount NFS without upgrading Knative.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend upgrading Knative.  It sounds like you're running a version from 2020, which won't have fixes for the (many) discovered vulnerabilities in the Knative dependency tree.  This includes a number of remote vulnerabilities in the go standard library.

Knative Serving has made a concerted stability effort since at least 0.20, testing availability while upgrading and downgrading the Knative version on the cluster.  Personally, I've upgraded since around 0.20 to 1.10 with no problems upgrading Knative once the underlying Kubernetes version was in the supported range.  (Upgrading Kubernetes versions, on the other hand, has been about a 50% initial success rate.)

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to rebuild the Knative 0.23 distribution from source (which should still be reproducible if you use the correct go compiler version), and then patch that version with the PVC code from the later release.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. We have upgraded the version of Knative in the testing environment, and currently, all applications are functioning normally.